# How to restrict " character to be changed into â€œ while exporting any textfield string value to csv in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have to export a NSTextfield string value to csv but if string value contains " character it gets converted to â€œ.

How can I restrict such behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code producing the issue in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What happens is when we have a textview and we type "Hello" in it. The resultant string comes as ""Hello""
But the same thing when we type in textfield then the string is seen as "\"Hello\"" which is correct.
So what is the way or any property when we type text in text view and text should be fetched as in text field.

The issue wont be seen if textview quotes can be replaced with escape sequence.